# How to custom menu like this

Tags: android, menu

I want a custom menu like this:

[image]

The normal of Android code is allow me to add 1 icon and 1 text in the menu. But I want to add more icon like the image above.

Comment: Please edit your question to post the [minimal code that reproduces the problem that you're asking about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Note that a lot of us want to help you, but please don't consider StackOverflow as free coding service. Don't just ask "I want to make this, how can I make this". Anyway, no hard feelings, and welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor Q? for next time I will ask the Q? with a good way. i'm very sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two ways to do this.

Using navigation view `app:headerLayout="@layout/yourLayout"` and setting a layout that you create whatever you want, then and your code:

```
NavigationView nav = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.yourNav);
Switch switch = (Switch)  nav.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.yourSwitch);
```

The second way to do this is using a custom library like this one: [SublimeNavigationView](https://github.com/vikramkakkar/SublimeNavigationView)

Comment: Now I custom new menu by delete the menu from menu.xml and custom in a header layour by Relative lay out